# Angular + Cordova - PIcture In Picture on mobile (PIP)

Tags: angular, cordova, cordova-plugins, picture-in-picture

I'm trying to implement Picture In Picture on mobile with Angular and Cordova.
I found this plugin, but I didn't manage to work with it:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-pip

I would appreciate your assistance with this matter